# Problem with decoding utf8 characters - šđžčć

Tags: go, utf

I have a word which contains some of these characters - šđžčć. When I take the first letter out of that word, I'll have a `byte`, when I convert that `byte` into string I'll get incorrectly decoded string.
Can someone help me figure out how to decode properly the extracter letter.
This is example code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    word := "ŠKOLA"
    c := word[0]

    fmt.Println(word, string(c)) // ŠKOLA Å
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6T2FX4vN3-U

Comment: When you take the first letter, you have a rune, not a byte.

Comment: Read https://blog.golang.org/strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Š` is more than one byte. One method to index runes is to convert the string to `[]rune`

```
c := []rune(word)[0]
```

https://play.golang.org/p/NBUopxe-ik1

You can also use the functions provided in the `utf8` package, like [`utf8.DecodeRune`](https://godoc.org/unicode/utf8#DecodeRune) and [`utf8.DecodeRuneInString`](https://godoc.org/unicode/utf8#DecodeRuneInString) to iterate over the individual codepoints in the utf8 string.

```
r, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(word)
fmt.Println(word, string(r))
```

Comment: Any comments on the `[]rune` conversion vs. [`utf8/DecodeRuneInString`](https://godoc.org/unicode/utf8#DecodeRuneInString)?

Comment: OP might find [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings) useful.

Comment: @TimCooper: the question didn't really describe the intent, but the `utf8` functions are also options I can add ;)

Comment: Thanks, a perfect answer